# What is an inexpensive way of converting arraybuffer to video file and adding moov atom to it?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, stream, buffer, fluent-ffmpeg

I am receiving chunks of data from client as such :

```
 let blob = new Blob(chunks, options);
        console.log(`blob.size`, blob.size);
        const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());
```

and then converting the `buffer` into mp4 by `FFMPEG` as such :

```
      const stream = Readable.from(buffer);
          ffmpeg().input(stream).videoCodec('libx264').format('mp4').outputOptions([
          "-movflags", "frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart",
          "-preset", "veryfast",
          "-crf", "30",
          ]).save(`${__dirname}/videos/foo.mp4`)
          .on('end', () => console.log('ended'))
          .on('error', (e) => console.log(e))
```

Yet this process has proven to be cpu heavy and I am looking for another inexpensive way of going from the `arraybuffer` to an mp4 file without having to max out my cpu load and having moov atom present on my video file.

How can I achieve this?